# typescript generic inference not as expected

Tags: typescript

Why is this Result not string, but unknown

```
type GetFunctionGenerics<F> = F extends <G extends infer R>()=>void ?R: never;
type Result = GetFunctionGenerics<<Y extends string>()=>void >
```